# Добавить в массив новой функции объекты из старой функции JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо из функции `Tools` передать один из `item`'ов в массив `Bag` функции `Equipment`.

```
function Equipment() {
  const Bag = [];

  function addProduct() {
    for (var i=0; i < tools; i++) {
      Bag.push(tools.item1)
    }
  }
}

function tools() {
    this.item1 = {
      name: "item1",
      price: 5,
      count: 10
    };
    this.item2 = {
      name: "item2",
      price: 15,
      count: 20
    };
    this.item3 = {
      name: "item3",
      price: 20,
      count: 30
    };
    this.item4 = {
      name: "item4",
      price: 30,
      count: 40
    };
    this.item5 = {
      name: "item5",
      price: 40,
      count: 50
    };
}
const equipment = new Equipment();
const tools = new Tools(/* … */);
equipment.addTools(tools)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы создаете объект tools с помощью функции конструктора:

```
const tools = new Tools(/* … */);
```

То функция у вас должна называться

```
function Tools() {
   ...
```

В итоге объект tools будет выглядеть так `{item1: ..., item2: ..., item3: ..., item4: ..., item5: ...}`

Так как айтемы вы записываете в свойства новосозданного объекта, то и обращаться к ним вы можете просто по имени.

```
function Equipment() {
  const Bag = [];

  this.addProduct = function (propertyName) {
    Bag.push(tools[propertyName]);
  }
}
```

Обратите внимания, что объекты и массивы передаются по ссылке, то есть если вы внутри Equipment потом будете изменять переданные объекты, то они изменятся и в изначальном объете tools.

Вот хороший учебник по JS: http://learn.javascript.ru/object

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы функция добавления `addProduct` добавляла объект через консоль? в данный момент пишет `item1 is not defined`

Comment: Если вы пишете в консоль, во время точки останова, и у вас к этому времени созданы tools и equipment, то equipment.addTools('item1'), должно работать. В метод передается строка.

Comment: Передается строкой, а каким образом можно сделать, чтобы передалось именно как объект. В последующем есть необходимость работать с `price` и `count` объекта. Пишу в консоль после загрузки страницы и объекты `tools` и `equipment` созданы